# array search using php

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code with sample array..if user searches for 523465 then index should return of main array userdb..ihave tried in several ways but failed to get correct output.can someone help me?

```
   <?php
   $userdb = Array (
        (0) => Array (
            (uid) => Array (
                    (0) => Array (
                            '10770' 
                    ),

                    (1) => Array (
                            '523465' 
                    ),

                    (2) => Array (
                            '4042389' 
                    ) 
            ),
            (name) => 'Sandra Shush',
            (url) => 'urlof100' 
    ),

    (1) => Array (
            (uid) => Array (
                    (0) => Array (
                            '102320' 
                    ),

                    (1) => Array (
                            '532465' 
                    ),

                    (2) => Array (
                            '40432389' 
                    ) 
            ),
            (name) => 'Stefanie Mcmohn',
            (pic_square) => 'urlof100' 
    ));
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(array_column ( $userdb, 'uid' ));
    $key = array_search ( 5432365, array_column ( $userdb, 'uid' ) );

    echo ("The key is: " . $key);
```

Comment: what is your accept  output?

Comment: suppose if i search for uid value 102320 then key value 1 should  returned by the code i.e the index of $userdb  main array should return..

Comment: Please see my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38995189/1960558

Comment: but i want index value

Comment: @user3860618, you should accept the answer which helped you to help community.

Answer (score 3):

Couple of foreach loop required. Here the function I wrote for you. First parameter is your array and 2nd parameter is the value you want to search.

```
function searchArrayKey($userdb,$given_value){

foreach ($userdb as $firstkey => $val) {

    foreach ($val as $secondkey => $nestedarray){

        foreach ($nestedarray as $thirdkey => $thirdnestedarray){
            if ($thirdnestedarray['0'] == $given_value){
                return $firstkey;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then use to get the key of the main array

```
print_r (searchArrayKey($userdb, 523465));
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of foreach loops would do the job:

```
function user_from_uid(array $usersdb, $uid){

    foreach($usersdb as $user){
        foreach($user['uid'] as $id){
            if($id==$uid){
                return $user;
            }
        }
    }
    //handle non existent user somehow
    return false; //or throw exception etc

}
```

If you are going to be accessing multiple users it might make sense to create a wrapper class that keeps a map of uid to user:

```
class UserList
{

    private $usersArray, $uidMap;

    function __construct($usersArray)
    {
        $this->usersArray = $usersArray;
        $this->uidMap=[];
        $this->createMap();
    }

    private function createMap()
    {
        foreach($this->usersArray as $key => $user){
            foreach($user['uid'] as $uid){
                $this->uidMap[$uid]=$key;
            }
        }
    }

    function getUserByUid($uid)
    {
        if(isset($this->uidMap[$uid])){
            return $this->usersArray[$this->uidMap[$uid]];
        }
        //handle non existent user somehow
        return false; //or throw exception etc        
    }   

} 

$userList = new UserList($usersdb);

$someUser = $userList->getUserByUid('523465');
$another  = $userList->getUserByUid('40432389');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach ($userdb as $key=> $db) {
    if (in_array($key, $db["uid"])) {
       $parent_key = $key;
       break;
    } 
 }

echo $parent_key;
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$key = '102320';
foreach($userdb as $user){
    foreach($user['uid'] as $id){
        if($id[0] == $key)      
        {
            echo "Match found--->".$key;
        }       
    }   
}
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/ppcLA)**

i hope it will be helpful.

Comment: its giving value not key